# How list or sell item in opensea using python

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, opensea

I am trying to sell my nft on opensea using python. I could create contract and mint an NFT. I can see the collection and Items in opensea. But how do I sell an item on opensea using python. I can do that on opensea web flow, but having 10k items in a collection, its very difficult to go to each item and sell.

Please help me out if anyone know how to do this using python

This is my contract address link in testnets [Click here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x6c317e7de3e8823bbc308a2912ba6f24587fc167)

I have observed open sea is calling approve method on sell, so I tried that as well, but could not see any updates on opnsea.

This is my collection in opensea testnets [Click here](https://testnets.opensea.io/collection/test-dynamic-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no API or SDK for python. I could achieve this using opensea-js SDK.